# Does heteroclinic intersections of the stable and unstable manifolds of different fixed points imply chaotic behavior?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, fixed-points, nonlinear-dynamics

Suppose we have a saddle fixed point of a map, then we have the stable and unstable manifolds of the saddle points. If the stable and unstable manifolds intersect (If they intersect once they will be intersecting infinite number of times) the map has chaotic behavior.

Now I am thinking what happens if the stable and unstable manifolds come from different fixed points?.

Suppose we have two different fixed points say $P1,P2$ of a map. Now if the unstable manifold of $P1$ intersects the stable manifold of $P2$, then can we say that the map is chaotic?. This is a kind of heteroclinic connection.

Comment: If I am remembering right, if there is a heteroclinic contour (i.e., $W^u_{P_1} \cap W^s_{P_2} \neq \emptyset$ and $W^u_{P_2} \cap W^s_{P_1} \neq \emptyset$) between $P_1$ and $P_2$, then there is also a Smale horseshoe, similar to the case of homoclinic loop to a saddle fixed point.

Comment: Hi Evgeny! thanks for your help, can you please give me some reference for this, like where it is stated? like a theorem / similar perhaps?

Comment: The simplest explanation probably would be in [What is a ... Blender?](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~wilkinso/papers/blendersonecolumn8august2016.pdf), Figure 3(b). It's very easy to show that geometrically there is a horseshoe, but to prove that expansion and contraction rates are exponential is a whole another story. Somewhere around p.16 in [On Newhouse Domains of Two-Dimensional Diffeomorphisms Which are Close to a Diffeomorphism with a Structurally Unstable Heteroclinic Cycle](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dturaev/mypapers/procsteklov1997.pdf) there is an example of how it looks like.

Comment: Oh nice! thanks Evgeny! will go through them :)